# Why cart icon is not showing?

Tags: html

could anyone let me know what's wrong and cart icon is not displayed?

```
`<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" class="rel">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />
   </head>
<body>
     <secton id="header">
        <a href="#"><img src="/logo.png" class="logo" alt=""></a> 
        <div>
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboyt.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
     </secton>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Tried different icons and it's not working anyway..

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/wordpress/ "To use Pro icons with the CDN, you need to add your site’s domain to the allowed domains on your Font Awesome CDN page. Once you add your domain(s) and save your plugin settings with Pro icons selected, your Pro icons will start showing up on your site."

Comment: Im just learning programming, do I really need to domain to use such icons in order to practice?

Comment: The `fa-bag-shopping` icon is not available in the library that you imported. Try `fa-bags-shopping`. Also add the class `fas` and check

Comment: @Weronika8088 Use the free icon sets if you don't want to pay for pro. Per https://fontawesome.com/account/cdn, that'll be something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">`, and you should limit your selections to those in the free library (https://fontawesome.com/v5/search?o=r&m=free).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proper class names

- `.fas` **not** `.fa-solid`
- `.fa-bags-shopping`, `.fa-shopping-bag`, `.fa-shopping-cart`, or `.fa-shopping-basket` **not** `.fa-bag-shopping`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />

<i class="fas fa-bags-shopping"></i>
<i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>
<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
<i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
```